# Get number of same rows in concat col in sql

Tags: sql, count, case, concatenation

I am trying to Concat( description, number, date) and then count like count(concat(description,number, date)) <=1 then ‘y’, else’’ end.

But I am getting error. I am trying to Concatenate three columns and want to return how many times a row appear in col. can you please advise

Comment: Please add your database to description and provide the error message

Comment: Case when count((concat([ description, [date],[number]) <=1 then’y’

Comment: I am getting error as number is invalid in the select list because it is not contained an suggested function or the group by clause

Comment: what do you like to receive with this query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the **complete** query you are using as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). [No screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Answer (score 0):

If you group by your concatenated string, you already get all the distinct combinations. Just add one more field to know how many times each row appears either with sum(1) or count(1)/count(*).

**EDIT**

```sql
SELECT concat(t1.description,t1,number, t1.date) AS UID,
CASE WHEN t2.NUM_TIMES_UID <= 1 THEN 'y' ELSE 'dummy' END AS DUMMY_VAR
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT
         concat(description,number, date) AS UID,
         SUM(1) AS NUM_TIMES_UID
     FROM table
     GROUP BY
         concat(description,number, date)
) t2 ON (concat(t1.description,t1,number, t1.date) = concat(t2.description,t2,number, t2.date))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need this in case statement to check if return rows next to concat more than once. How I will do this?

Comment: Thank you, but when I am joining this to main query it is giving me error. Sorry I am new to SQL

Answer (score 0):

Simple decision returning grouped rows and count of times this row exists in input table:

```
with items as (
select concat(description,number, date) as item
from table1
group by concat(description,number, date)
)

select item, count(item) as item_cnt
from items
group by item
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26179194)